# PHP GD creating image using a function

Tags: php, php-gd

I don't understand why one of the lines is not being drawn in the following code:

```
<?php
    $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);

    $white = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 255, 255);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 0, 0, 0);

    imagefill($canvas,0,0,$black);

    function myLine()
    {
        imageline($canvas, 0,20,100,20,$white);
    }

    imageline($canvas, 0,60,100,60,$white); //this line is printed..
    myLine(); //but this line is not

    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($canvas);
    imagedestroy($canvas);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you refer to `$canvas` and `$white` variables within the `myLine` function, and these variables are not available in the [scope](http://php.net/language.variables.scope) of this function. You should either pass them as arguments, or use [`global` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global).

**Example**

```
function myLine($canvas, $color) {
  imageline($canvas, 0,20,100,20, $color);
}

myLine($canvas, $white);
```

You can also use an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) as follows:

```
$my_line = function() use ($canvas, $white) {
    imageline($canvas, 0,20,100,20, $white);
};

$my_line();
```

In this code, the `$canvas` and `$white` variables are taken from the current scope.